# Three.js vertices position not updating with custom shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a custom shader in three.js to allow me to set individual vertices color, size and position.

Color and size work fine but when I update the vertex x,y or z it's not updated on screen.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cmg0z2f/1/)

What am I missing?

**Vertex shaders:**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader">

  attribute float size;
  attribute vec3 color;

  varying vec3 vColor;
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() 
  {
    vColor = color;
    gl_PointSize = size;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }

</script>
```

**Fragment shader**

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader">

  uniform sampler2D texture;

  varying vec2 vUv;
  varying vec3 vColor;

  void main() 
  {
    vec4 color = vec4(vColor, 1);
    gl_FragColor = color;
  }

</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
camera.position.z = 100;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var vShader = document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent;
var fShader = document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent;

var uniforms = {};

var attributes = {
  color: { type: 'c', value: [] },
  size:  { type: 'f', value: [] }
};

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) 
{
  var angle = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  var radius = 40 + (Math.random() * 5);

  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
  vertex.x = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
  vertex.y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
  vertex.z = 0; 

  attributes.size.value[i] = Math.random() * 10;
  attributes.color.value[i] = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );

  geometry.vertices.push( vertex );
}

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(
{ 
  uniforms: uniforms,
  attributes: attributes,
  vertexShader: vShader,
  fragmentShader: fShader,
  transparent: true
});

var particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud(geometry, material);
scene.add( particleSystem );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x292B30, 1 );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

animate();

function animate() 
{
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}

function render() 
{
  for (var i = geometry.vertices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    geometry.vertices[i].z = geometry.vertices[i].z - 0.5 ;
  }

  camera.lookAt( scene.position );
  //particleSystem.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true;
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When modifying the vertex position, set the `verticesNeedUpdate` flag:

`geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;`

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1cmg0z2f/2/

Three.js r71, due to changes in `ShaderMaterial` the fiddle doesnt work with the new version.

Comment: Awesome, I had particleSystem.geometry.__dirtyVertices = true; but that seemed to do nothing, perhaps that's old code? But anyways working a treat now, thanks!

Comment: Yes, pre-r49. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates on how to update the other attributes.

Comment: I suspect the property changed from `verticesNeedUpdate` to `needsUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to the previous accepted answer but just in case here's an updated answer

`geometry.attributes[attributeName].needsUpdate = true`

eg

`geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true`

---

*keep in mind that this works for custom / shader attributes that you've added using `setAttribute`, which is what I was searching for before I found this QA.*